# Why does Java allow a compare(String, String) Comparator method to take arguments of Object type?

Tags: java, comparator

So here is my code:

```
public class Demo {

    public static final Comparator<String> SORT_BY_LENGTH = new SortByLength();

    private static class SortByLength implements Comparator<String>{
        public int compare(String w, String v) {
            return w.length()-v.length();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o1 = "abc", o2 = "bc";
        Comparator c = SORT_BY_LENGTH;
        System.out.println(c.compare(o1, o2));//OK, output 1
    }
}
```

So what confuses me is that the signature of the compare() method takes 2 String variables as argument. However, even when I input 2 arguments of Object type, it still works. Why is that?

PS: if I define some ordinary method as follows, then the compiler will complain there is an error, because Object cannot be converted to String.

```
public static int foo(String w, String v) {
    return w.length()-v.length();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o1 = "abc", o2 = "bc";
    System.out.println(foo(o1, o2));// compiling error!
}
```

Comment: basically: because it is an inherited/implemented method, and the original class/interface can not possibly know which types will (come to) exist, so they are defined as Object, since every instance of any class will, in fact, be an Object

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Because you are using `Comparator` and not `Comparator<String>` as the type. That way there will be no compile time check (well there is but the type is now `Object` and not `String`. If you change `Comparator c =` to `Comparator<String> c = ` it will work.

Comment: change `Comparator c = SORT_BY_LENGTH;` to `Comparator<String> c = SORT_BY_LENGTH;` and see what happens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Object` as arguments here because you used the *raw type* of `Comparator`, which is something that you generally should not do.

Here is where you did it:

```
Comparator c = SORT_BY_LENGTH;
```

See how there are not generic arguments to `Comparator`? That is a sign of using raw types. You can assign any instance of a parameterised type, like `SORT_BY_LENGTH` to a raw type. However, since the raw type `Comparator` has no generic parameters, its `compare` method takes two `Object`s instead of `String`s. So you can theoretically pass anything into `compare`.

However, if the wrong type of object goes into the method, an exception will be thrown. Try putting two `new Object()` in there!

This is why you should not assign parameterised types to raw types. They are not type safe. You should do something like this instead:

```
Comparator<String> c = SORT_BY_LENGTH;
```

or use `SORT_BY_LENGTH` directly.

If you made the above change, the call to `compare` will not compile anymore, because it is expecting `String`s. You should change the type of `o1` and `o2` to `String`.